# Stopping bubbling/propagation in Ember 2.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Is there a proper way to stop bubbling in this scenario in Ember 2.18? I couldn't find an example that matched in the docs, but managed to find two other examples around the web. Both work, but one looks like it might be deprecated as I couldn't find references to it in the newest versions of Ember docs.

Scenario:
I have a container. I want to click on it to expand/open it. Inside the container, I have a button. I want to click the button to close it. The general issue is that clicking the button to close also triggers the parent container's click event to open.

To solve, I believe I need to prevent bubbling/propagation when the button is clicked.

The two solutions I have found are as follows:

Solution #1:

> event.stopPropagation();

Component JS:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  tagName: "section",
  classNames: ["Container"],
  classNameBindings: ['isOpen:Container--open'],
  isOpen: false,

  click() {
    if (!this.get('isOpen')) {
      this.send('openContainer');
    }
  },

  actions: {
    openContainer() {
      this.toggleProperty('isOpen');
      // JS removed for demo
    },

    closeContainer(event) {
      this.toggleProperty('isOpen');
      // JS removed for demo
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
});
```

Component HBS:

```
<button onclick={{action 'closeContainer'}}>Close</button>
```

Solution #2:

> bubbles=false

Component JS:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  tagName: "section",
  classNames: ["Container"],
  classNameBindings: ['isOpen:Container--open'],
  isOpen: false,

  click() {
    if (!this.get('isOpen')) {
      this.send('openContainer');
    }
  },

  actions: {
    openContainer() {
      this.toggleProperty('isOpen');
      // JS removed for demo
    },

    closeContainer() {
      this.toggleProperty('isOpen');
      // JS removed for demo
    }
  }
});
```

Component HBS:

```
<button {{action 'closeContainer' bubbles=false}}>Close</button>
```

All feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

The below is current Ember 2.18 method for handling event bubbling.

```
// No bubbling
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  doubleClick() {
    alert('DoubleClickableComponent was clicked!');
  }
});

// Allow bubbling
import Component from '@ember/component';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Component.extend({
  doubleClick() {
    Ember.Logger.info('DoubleClickableComponent was clicked!');
    return true;
  }
});
```

[Ember Guides Handling Events](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/components/handling-events/#toc-toggle)

Your second solution using `bubbles=false` is still acceptable in Ember 2.18. See event propagation.

[Template Helper Method Action](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.18/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods)

Again, my apologies for misreading your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Paul, but I'm not sure I follow. If I don't use the click event handler in the component JS, how would I call the openContainer action when the container is clicked? Keep in mind, I don't want the button to both open & close the container. The button is hidden within the container when closed. Clicking the container should open it, but once the container is open, only the button should close it.